# what is the correct activity name for android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-manifest

I have been trying to change the package name of an android project in android studio

in the AndroidManifest.xml I've changed the package name

but down in the activity tag it looks like this:

[image]

showing the old & the new package name beside each other with a red labeled as error maybe?

I'm new to android and I've been searching and can't figure out what should I type in here? which one is correct?

thanks for helping..

Comment: what if i'm a beginner and ask a question that may be "silly" or "stupid" to you, you give me a -1 without even commenting an advice or something to correct my situation!

Comment: Saif one suggestion is to never put code in image, pass it as text in the question. (people auto down vote if they see code image, since this is not useful for future users that use search engine to find your problem)

Comment: @PetterFriberg thank you for that useful information i will consider it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your activity is composed by its package + "." + it's name. Look for the "AndroidLauncher.java" file in your project, check the package declaration, and edit your manifest accordingly.

Comment: okay I checked the package declaration in AndroidLauncher.java it's as I changed it, i also did in manifest. now the activity name would be the package name + "." + any name I choose? Thanks

Comment: No, it's the name of the class file itself without the ".java" extension.

Comment: Think of the "name" attribute as a "path" to the class file, but with dashes replaced by dots.

Comment: sorry for being so stupid but I can't find my class file and don't know what its name,the matter is that i imported this project from eclipse and I don't it's content

Comment: Double click the shit key and type AndroidLauncher. It will show up. Then just press enter to open up the file.

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew that AndroidLauncher.java is the same class file

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the Project. If it doesn't work, remove tags and add activity again to manifest. Hope this works.

Comment: I already cleaned still the same. I wanted to edit the activity by myself but I don't know what the activity should contains or what the activity name actually represents. I'm new to android and imported this project from eclipse

Comment: Activity name started with . is added to the package name you specified in manifest file. Also if you place your activity classes under separate package (folder in navigator) you must provide its name, like .ui.activity.Main

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on your root project directory
2. Select Refactor -> Rename
3. Select rename project and change the name there.
4. Also Select rename module and change it there as well. If you get an message saying module name already changed thats fine.
5. Now right-click on the project root folder again and select Open Module Settings.
6. Under the Modules section remove whatever folders are associated to your old project name.
7. Apply Settings and hit OK.
8. Restart Android Studio.